# Comments in version history

Tags: office-365

In Office365 files (e.g. Excel, Powerpoint, Word), is it possible to comment the version history to identify specific instances? E.g. "This version was shown in the meeting with xy"? This would make it a lot easier to restore a specific version.

I found that there is a comment field when performing a check-in, but I don't know where I can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the version history of an individual file, you can find it here, click on the little stacked dots, then select version history from the options that appear.

[image: version history screen shot]

The document library where my file is saved does not have check-in enabled, but as you see in the picture below, it does still show a Comments field, even though it is blank.

[image]

If check-in was enabled, the user that is checking-in a document has an opportunity to type something in the Comments fields, though people are lazy and often don't bother.

UPDATED - in response to your comment

Well, users have a choice of accessing the version history to see the comments (assuming check-in/check-out is enabled) or else the **check-in comments** field can be added to the default view, so they wouldn't need to go to the version history menu to see the **check-in comments**.  The trouble you'll likely have is lazy users not bothering to type in a comment; however it's for managers/supervisors to enforce the rule if the business really needs to know this information.  I'd do it this way, if you really want users to explain the changes made to the file.

[image: check-in comments in Sharepoint]

### OR....

If you want to go all 'Robocop' on them, you could even add in an extra step; for documents being checked-in, you could use a Flow to add an approval step.  The approval would need to come from a manager or supervisor; they review the change and they're not happy with it, they reject and the lazy person updating the file has to do it again before the document can be approved to become the 'live, updated' version of the file.  It the new draft is rejected, it does back to the user.

### Here's a totally different approach, which I wouldn't recommend.

But if you don't want to use 'Check-in/check-out' documents, you could try using the Word property, **Comments**, instead.  You won't be able to get this property to display inside Sharepoint though, so it seems a bit pointless to me, since you'd have to open up the file in order to view the 'Word Comments '.

[image: Word Properties screen]

Comment: Thanks! But is there also a way to access it from Excel/Word/Powerpoint directly? Navigating to the Sharepoint web page is a path hardly anybody is going to go...

Comment: Thank you for your update regarding my comment. However, I'd like to see the comment directly from Powerpoint/etc. directly *without* having to navigate to the browser page...